# update blank fields in excel file based another record with matching id on before migrating to ssis

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I'm working on an excel file that has an employee id, dependent type, name, address, city, and state field, all records have the employeeid, dependent type, and name fields filled out, 1 family has 1 employee id, but dependent type varies from 1 to 2 (1 being self,  2 dependent) but only the address, city, and state fields are filled in when the dependent type field = 1, when 2 those fields are blank, I want to update dependent type 2 address city and state fields with dependent type 1 values based on the matching employeeid. I would like to do this in Excel before I import it through ssis into my sql table. But if I can do it only in sql what code would needed to be used.

[Excel file ]
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would NOT fill in any of that. I would load into 2 tables:

Table1:
Employee: EmpID, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, State

Table 2:
Dependant: EmpID, FirstName, LastName

Using SSIS:

1. Load all columns into DataFlow
2. Use conditional Split to redirect output based on record type
3. Map each output into the table

Then you can use SQL to tie them back together (on EmpID) and the addresses will flow together

Comment: hello, I have 1 target table that requires the fields to be all be present

Comment: Well that is poor table design for many reasons. Here are two. The employee's address is not a certain match to a dependent and repetition of values in columns (normalization).